# Simple phone number regex, starting zero optional, no separators

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex that works specifically for my country, Venezuela, for our mobile phone providers. So, the number can only begin with 0412 | 0414 | 0416 | 0424 | 0426, and also I'm trying to make the starting 0 optional. From there on, the number is always 7 digits long. Meaning that the complete phone number is 10 to 11 digits long, and the first 4 must be either 412 | 414 | 416 | 424 | 426, with an optional leading zero. All of this is intended for a C# application. Thanks!

I have tried with the following and variations thereof:

```
((0?(412|414|416|424|426))\d{3}|\d{4})\d{7}
```

and `www.regexr.com` (great site, by the way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the complete phone number is 10 to 11 digits long

This might help you

```
0?4(12|14|16|24|26)[0-9]{7}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7jF9/8)

Pattern explanation:

```
  0?                       '0' (optional)

  4                        '4'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    12                       '12'
   |                        OR
    14                       '14'
   |                        OR
    16                       '16'
   |                        OR
    24                       '24'
   |                        OR
    26                       '26'
  )                        end of \1

  [0-9]{7}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (7 times)
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
0?4(1[246]|2[46])[0-9]{7}
```

To explain:

- The `?` means the `0` is optional
- `[246]` matches either a `2`, a `4` or a `6` (character based)
- `(abc|xyz)` matches either `abc` or `xyz` (subexpression based)
- `{n}` means match `n` times

Comment: I think I would've said `4[12][246]` to keep it cleaner... but good adaptation.

Comment: @vapcguy That would mean that the prefixes `422` and `0422` would also match - which they should not.